# mysql find out the non repeated customers

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this, 
`test@text.com`
`test12@text.com`
`test123@text.com`
`test12@text.com`
`test@text.com`
`test12@text.com`
`test1@text.com`

I want the email which are not repeated such as result will be 
`test1@text.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table name is `sample_table` your column name is `sample_column`.

Try this

```
select sample_column 
from sample_table 
group by sample_column 
having count(sample_column)=1;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4bbda/7)

Comment: Hi i checked randomly, but the result is not perfect.

Comment: What exactly does `not perfect` mean? Give some sample data and examples.

Answer (score 0):

You  can try this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT(email_column_name) 
from tableName 
GROUP BY email_column_name;
```

and if you want more columns information related row then try this.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT(email_column_name), ID, firstName,LastName 
 from tableName 
 GROUP BY email_column_name;
```

Comment: With distinct the result will be test@text.com test12@text.com test123@text.com test1@text.com

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(email_column_name), ID, firstName, LastName
```

DISTINCT works on all columns selected, it is not a function where you can apply it to a single column in the select. So if an email were to appear twice with a different last name that email would be returned in both cases.